# Using a Variable of an Instance within the Method of another Class in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I would go about using a variable of a specific instance of a class within a function of another class.

To provide an example of what I'm trying to do, say I've 3 classes a,b and c. Class c inherits from class b, and a single instance of b and c are  called within a method in class a and b respectively. How would I go about using the variable of int pos (see below) within a specific instance of class a in class c?

```
class a
{
    private:
    void B(); //Calls an instance of class c
    int pos; //Variable that I want to use in c
};

class b : public c
{
    private:
    void C(); //Calls an instance of class b
};

class c
{
    private:
    void calculate(int _pos); //Method which requires the value of pos from class a 
};
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does `c::calculate` have to be private? Otherwise `a` could call `.calculate` off of the `c` object it instantiated.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't make much sense. As well as there's not really a question.

Comment: Doesn't have to be private, just tried it and it works. Thank you!

Comment: @user3166884 _"Doesn't have to be private, "_ It ***should*** be `private` (or at least `protected`) with a good class design!

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample doesn't make much sense for me, and you aren't really clear what you want to achieve.

> *"How would I go about using the variable of int pos (see below) within a specific instance of class a in class c?"*

Fact is you can't access any `private` class member variables from other classes.

Since `class c` and `class b` aren't declared as `friend` for `class a`, these cannot access the `pos` member from `a::pos` directly. You have to pass them a reference to `class a;` at some point, and provide public (read access) to `pos` with a getter function :

```
class a {
    int pos; //Variable that I want to use in c
public:
    int getPos() const { return pos; } // <<< let other classes read this 
                                       //     property
};
```

And use it from an instance of `class c()` like e.g. (constructor):

```
c::c(const a& a_) { // <<< pass a reference to a 
   calculate(a_.getPos());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but if you want to access a member of a class instance from a non-friend non-base class, that member must be exposed of there must be some function that access it. For example:

```
class a
{
public:
  int getPos() const { return pos; }
private:
  void B(); //Calls an instance of class c
  int pos; //Variable that I want to use in c
};
```

Comment: This is still backwards because `a` will have a `c`, not the other way around. `c` isn't aware of class `a` at all, so a getter for an attribute of `a` will be of no use.